# Cannot find type '*' in scope on Xcode 12 with M1 Chip

Tags: swift, xcode, admob, in-app-purchase, apple-m1

I just started a new project on Xcode 12 with Apple M1 Chip. I did run into issues when I was installing the pods but I was able to fix them using `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` then `arch -x86_64 pod install`. Now, the issue that I am facing is when I added the in-app purchases and the admob pod for ads. I got an error that said `Cannot find type 'SKProduct' in scope` and `Cannot find type 'GADInterstitial' in scope`. I changed the Validate Workspace to `YES` in the Build Settings and that did not fix it.

[image: Here are the errors that I'm facing.]

Comment: did you import necessary libraries into `MainViewController`?

Comment: Yes I did. But they still did not work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Any luck yet?

Answer (score 1):

GADInterstitial was rename in GADInterstitialAd Google Ads v 8.0.0

See all renamed classes
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration#class_renames

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same errors:
Cannot find type 'SKProduct' in scope and Cannot find type 'GADInterstitial' in scope. I use Firebase in the project. In pod file when I changed **pod 'Firebase/Analytics'** to **pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'** then open xcworkspace from terminal and then clean the project the problem has been solved.

Comment: Can you add some context to your answer? You may have fixed it, but your answer is lacking clarity. It is common to new contributors to fall into that trap. Understandable.

Comment: even if this worked for you. as you see my app uses in app purchases which I need to import StoreKit for that. The StoreKit does not have a pod name or anything such that. in order for you to integrate StoreKit you have to select the framework in Xcode. if I was able to fix the firebase then I'm still stuck with StoreKit